# MySQL Combine Two Very Large Tables when three columns are equal

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have two very large tables, Table1 and Table2.  They look like this:

Table1 (800k records): Name, BirthDate, OrderNumber, col4, col5, col6.

Table2 (200k records): Name, BirthDate, OrderNumber, col4, col5, col6.

How can I select all records from table 1 which don't have a matching Name, BirthDate, OrderNumber combination in table 2?  The rest of the columns don't matter.

I've tried doing this query below which runs for at least a couple minutes with no apparent end.  Right now I am just trying to select the records then i can figure out how to combine the tables.

```
Select Table1.Name, Table1.BirthDate, Table1.OrderNumber from Table1
left join Table2 ON 
Table1.Name=Table2.Name AND
Table1.BirthDate=Table2.BirthDate AND
Table1.OrderNumber=Table2.OrderNumber AND 
WHERE Table2.Name IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this variation and see if it's any better. You should also make sure you have Name, BirthDate and OrderNumber indexed.

```
SELECT t1.Name, t1.BirthDate, t1.OrderNumber
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                         FROM Table2 t2
                         WHERE t2.Name = t1.Name
                             AND t2.BirthDate = t1.BirthDate
                             AND t2.OrderNumber = t1.OrderNumber)
```

Comment: I tried this one, it's been running for a couple minutes without any result so far.

Comment: @Ray And the indexing I mentioned exists?

Comment: Yes, of course.  Sorry I forgot to mention that I thought it was obvious with a table this big =)

Answer (score 2):

I would be surprised if you can beat the query you included as a part of your question during the query phase.

Not to belabor the point, but I suspect that your indexing needs to be updated.  For this query to work fast, I believe that you need one index on each of the two tables, where that index is on `(Name, BirthDate, OrderNumber)`.  This is very different from three independent indexes on those columns.

You could also accomplish this by setting an appropriate primary key, that is `PRIMARY KEY (Name, BirthDate, OrderNumber)`.

If my guess is incorrect, then it would be helpful to see the results of a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on each of the tables.

Comment: Thanks that's a good idea for a multiple column index.  I can't do a primary key though because one of the fields can be null sometimes.  I'll try with a multiple column index for now.

Comment: Thanks for the response it helped spawn my final idea that worked.  My main goal was to merge everything from the smaller table into the larger table.  So I just made a unique composite key across those 3 columns and did an "Insert Ignore" so it automatically excluded the columns that caused a conflict.